# How do I show a loading indicator before loading a WebView?

Tags: flutter, webview, loading

I want to use the [flutter_spinkit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinkit) and display one of the spinners before my WebView is loaded. It takes a few seconds for the calendar website to load so I want to have a spinner while it loads.

Thank you!

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class HS extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("High School Calendar"),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF04103E),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl: "https://calendar.google.com",
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';

class HS extends StatelessWidget {
  bool loading = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("High School Calendar"),
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF04103E),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: loading
            ? WebView(
                initialUrl: "https://calendar.google.com",
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onPageFinished: handleLoad(),
              )
            : SpinKitCircle(),
      ),
    );
  }

  handleLoad() {
    loading = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   late bool loadingPage = true;
.
.
.

//builder

var webv = WebView(
  initialUrl: widget.url,
  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  navigationDelegate: widget.onNavigation,
  onPageFinished: (url) => setState(() => loadingPage = false),
);

return loadingPage ? Stack(children: [webv, isLoading()]) : webv;
```

Answer (score -1):

Assign a Boolean variable as true globally and change when the page finished. You can have a look "onPage" properties in WebView.

```
  child: something ? WebView(
              initialUrl: "https://calendar.google.com",
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onPageFinished: _handleLoad,
            ): YourIndicator(),
    
    _handleLoad(){
setState(() { something = false; });
     
    }
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I updated the post with my new code.

Comment: switch to stateful widget not stateless

Comment: Still doesn't show. I think the WebView just loads and it's just the internet connection.

Comment: updated my answer. Forgot to add setState in the function

Comment: this is wrong solution, in this case it will keep loading forever